# Abort image upload on a server

Tags: android, http-post

I have an AsyncTask which upload an image to my server. This part works fine, but I can't figure out how to handle an aborting process. I have a ProgressDialog which is cancelable, and a listener on cancel. In this listener I abort the http request and the the AsyncTask... But it seems it is not enough as the image is still uploaded.
Here is how my code looks like :

```
public class UploadCubeThread extends AsyncTask<Cube, Void, String> {

private static final String url = "http://www.mywebsite.com/upload_cube.php";
private volatile HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
private ProgressDialog waitSpinner;
private Context context;
private HashMap<String, Integer> feedback;
private boolean success = false;

public UploadCubeThread(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.feedback = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    waitSpinner = new ProgressDialog(context);
    // Cancelable
    waitSpinner.setCancelable(true);
    waitSpinner.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
    waitSpinner.setOnCancelListener(new OnCancelListener() {
        public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
            httppost.abort();
            UploadCubeThread.this.cancel(true);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onCancelled() {
    super.onCancelled();
    success = false;
    feedback.put("cancelled", 0);
    ((UploadListener) context).onUploadComplete(success, feedback);
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    waitSpinner.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.uploading));
    waitSpinner.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Cube... arg0) {

    Cube cube = arg0[0];
    String result = null;
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    // Compression
    cube.getImage().compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, stream);

    byte[] byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
    String image_str = Base64.encodeBytes(byte_arr);
    ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair>();
    // Hash md5 pour l'intégrité
    String hash = CubeUploader.encode(image_str);

    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image", image_str));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_building", String
            .valueOf(cube.getId_building())));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("title", cube.getTitle()));
    nameValuePairs
            .add(new BasicNameValuePair("content", cube.getContent()));
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hash", hash));

    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs,
                HTTP.UTF_8));

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);


        // Utilisation de la réponse
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        result = reader.readLine();

    } catch (UnknownHostException he) {
        Log.e("CubeUpload", "Unknown Host : problem of connectivity ?");
        result = "host_pb";
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("CubeUpload", "Error during upload: " + e.toString());
    }
    return result;

}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
//Some process
    ((UploadListener) context).onUploadComplete(success, feedback);
    waitSpinner.dismiss();
}
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think the point is that `httppost.abort();`
is not enough and the connection is not completely closed (it's what I want, it'll be handled server side) so I tried to add `httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();` after but it's not better, the image is still uploaded ! ... I don't understand

Comment: im facing the same problem! ... did u manage to find a solution to this ?

Comment: yeah me 2 i have same problem plz if found find a solution post it here